# Save opengl Texture into Byte array

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I drew a circle using opengl in MFC, and now i want to read that texture and store it in a byte array. How to do that?
I drew the circle and tried to store the texture using below code, but it doesnt work

```
GLfloat glRadius = 0.5f;

GetDlgItem( IDC_SAVE_BUTTON )->EnableWindow( TRUE );        // To make button Enabled
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glGenTextures( 2, &m_glTexture[1] );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_glTexture[1] );
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glColor3f( 0,1,0 );
glVertex2d( 0, 0 );
int nSegments = 100;
GLfloat glAngle ;

for( int nIndex = 0 ;nIndex <= nSegments; nIndex++ )
{
    glAngle = ( nIndex* 2.0f * PI )/ nSegments;
    glVertex2d( cos( glAngle ) * glRadius , sin( glAngle ) * glRadius );
}
glEnd();
glGetTexLevelParameterfv( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &m_glTextureWidth );
glGetTexLevelParameterfv( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &m_glTextureHeight );
m_pbyImageData1 = new BYTE[ 4 * ( int )m_glTextureWidth * ( int )m_glTextureHeight ];
//glGetTexImage( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pbyImageData1 );
glReadPixels( 0, 0, m_glTextureWidth, m_glTextureHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pbyImageData1 );
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SwapBuffers( m_hDeviceContextDC );
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Empty array? null pointer?

Comment: Can you please post an explanation of "doesn't work"?

Comment: i used another width n height and i got the answer

Comment: now my issue is when i try to display it it shows another background along with the image

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing to the window, not a texture. glGetTexLevelParameterfv return the height and width of the bound texture which you by the way have not even loaded with anything. Bet they are both 0.

Call: `glReadPixels( 0, 0, window_width, window_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pbyImageData1 );`

Comment: I got the result. Now my problem is when i try to display that byte array , i'm getting the circle as well as a green background, i just need the circle i drew, i dont know how the background appears. Please help me.

Comment: BYTE* pbyNewImageData = NULL;
     pbyNewImageData = new BYTE[ CIRCLEWIDTH * CIRCLEHEIGHT * 3];
     glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
     glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glGenTextures( 1, &m_glTexture[1] );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_glTexture[1] );
    glColorMaterial( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,     GL_MODULATE ); 
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,     GL_NEAREST );

Comment: glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT ); 
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, CIRCLEWIDTH, CIRCLEHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pbyNewImageData ); 
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_glTexture[1] );
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glTexCoord2d( 0.0,0.0 ); 
glVertex2f( -0.8f, -0.8f ); 
glTexCoord2d( 1.0,0.0 );
glVertex2f( 0.8f, -0.8f );
glTexCoord2d( 1.0,1.0 );
glVertex2f( 0.8f, 0.8f );
glTexCoord2d( 0.0,1.0 );

Comment: glVertex2f( -0.8f, 0.8f );
glEnd();
SwapBuffers( m_hDeviceContextDC );
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
delete[] pbyNewImageData;

Comment: const int CIRCLEWIDTH = 700;
const int CIRCLEHEIGHT = 500;
const int CIRCLEPIXEL = 3;

Comment: Change texture environment to GL_REPLACE instead of modulate.